# In powerpoint, is there anyway to have "resize shape to fix text" to only grow horizontally?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, shapes

I am trying to figure out if there is a way in powerpoint when i am using "[Resize shape to fix text](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/text-autofit-in-powerpoint-2013.html)" i can make the vertical height of a shape fix and if the text in a shape can't fit that the shape only grows horizontally.

Is this possible as it seems like the default behavior is to grow only vertically

Answer (score 2):

Choose "Resize shape to fit text" but remove the check next to "Wrap text in shape"

Then the text box will grow in width to contain text as you add it.  You'll have to press ENTER or SHIFT+ENTER to add paragraph/line breaks as needed since PPT won't wrap lines for you with these settings.